# How to access wordpress admin using CakePHP username and password?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I want to integrate Wordpress blog in my Cake PHP Site.

When I logged in from My Site Admin, I need to automatic logged in Wordpress.

So How to integrate wordpress admin with my Site Admin.

For Example :

I was working on a site of Cakephp which was successfully delivered.But recently Client again appered and asked me to put the Wordpress blog in it,to cover up the Blogging thing in his site.He wants to share the authentication between the Cakephp and WP.Whoever registers in his site,then Logins in it and if he clicks on the Blog Tab,he must be redirected to the WP blog with the session still there.After some googling I have installed it in /app/webroot/blog folder but I am not able to edit the .htaccess file. Please help me in the right direction,that how to share the authentication betwenn Cake Php and Wordpress, and the second one how to customize the .htaccess file so that URL's look good.

So please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Kanji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CakePHP you can have access to multiple databases. Why not configure cake to have access to WP and use their login on the entire website? You can link the user information to the ID in the WP database and tie it to the content in the CakePHP specific database. Since you are using CakePHP, this should actually be quite simple too.